# REGEX - Cut a text between number and letter

Tags: text, python-3.x

Is it possible to use a regex so as to obtain the following features ?

```
text       = "123abcd56EFG"
listWanted = ["123", "abcd", "56", "EFG"]
```

The idea is to cut the texte each time one digit is followed by one letter, or one letter is followed by one digit.

### The solution thanks to the following answer

```
import re

pattern = r'(\d+|\D+)'

text  = "123abcd56EFG"
print(re.split(pattern, text))

text  = "abcd56EFG"
print(re.split(pattern, text))
```

This code will give...

```
['', '123', '', 'abcd', '', '56', '', 'EFG', '']
['', 'abcd', '', '56', '', 'EFG', '']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to do a split using: `\d+|\D+` as your Regex.

--note that you need excape sequences to make the `\` in your string, so the actual text entered will be: `"\\d+|\\D+"`

UNLESS, as noted in the comment below, you use a raw string, in which case it would be `r"\d+|\D+"` or `r'\d+|\D+'`

Comment: Unless you use a raw string, in case it would be `r"\d+|\D+"` (or `r'\d+|\D+'`).

Answer (score 1):

Use a capturing group in your regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> text  = "123abcd56EFG"
>>> pattern = r'(\d+)'
>>> re.split(pattern, text)
['', '123', 'abcd', '56', 'EFG']
```

While this will give you empty strings at the start and/or end for lines with digit groups at the start and/or end, those are easy enough to trim off.